# Problemas com cache do Navegador do lado do cliente

Tags: php, html, css

Surgiu um problema na minha aplicação que desenvolvi aqui no estágio.
Eu estou fazendo minha máquina de servidor pra um página web que eu desenvolvi.
Só que, após alguns acessos por partes dos clientes no nosso site, os dados param de atualizar, e só voltam a atualizar, se os clientes limparem o cache do navegador deles. Alguém poderia me informar que tipo de problema é esse? 
Grato

Comment: Quais tipos de dados? Poste um trecho do código! Dê mais informações refente ao problema pra que possamos te ajudar.